# header sticks to top of page in only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky-footer, removeclass

So I have a piece of jquery that will stick a div to the top of the page once scrolled past, this works well !!

now im trying to set it so one the bottom on that div is reached it stops sticking to the head, I can seem to work this.

any help is appreciated.

```
function sticky_relocate() {

var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
}
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1400) {
    $('sticky-anchor').slideDown();
}

else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
}
```

}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
$('#sticky').removeClass('#stick');
```

be

```
$('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
```

??

Comment: good spot, but still dose not do what i intended it to do. thanks though.